# How can I change an attribute trait_type value (from a int to a str) in multiple JSON files using a Python script?

Tags: python, attributes

```
"attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Vintage",
      "value": 2019
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Volume (ml)",
      "value": 750
    }
]
```

**I want to change the 2019 and the 750 to a string (by including "") for multiple values over 150+ JSONs using python**

I am not a dev and do not use Python, but I have this so far:

```
import json

for i in range(1, 147):
    with open(f'{i}.json', 'r+', encoding='utf8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Do these values stay in the same place for all of the JSON files?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that takes a JSON file name and replaces these specific values you're looking for:

```py
def change_values_to_string(json_filename):
    with open(f'{json_filename}.json', 'r') as json_fp:
        json_to_dict = json.loads(json_fp.read())

    for sub_dict in json_to_dict["attributes"]:
        sub_dict["value"] = str(sub_dict["value"])

    with open(f'{json_filename}.json', 'w') as json_fp:
        json_fp.write(json.dumps(json_to_dict))


for _ in range(1, 147):
    change_values_to_string(_)
```

Input:

```json
test.json

{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Vintage",
      "value": 2019
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Volume (ml)",
      "value": 750
    }
]
}
```

Calling the function with the correct file name: `change_values_to_string("test")`
Outputs:

```json
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Vintage",
      "value": "2019"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Volume (ml)",
      "value": "750"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Explanations:

1. Open the json file in read mode - and loading it into a dictionary python type.
2. Iterate over the `attributes` key which contains a lot of dictionaries if I get it right.
3. Replace each `value` key to a string
4. Dump the dictionary into the same file overriding it.